# How to use inotify with PHP7.4

Tags: inotify, php-7.4

I was using the PECL extension `inotify` with PHP 7.3.x without any problem. I updated to PHP 7.4 but I do not succeed to obtain the `inotify` extension compiled for the build `20190902` as the PECL command `sudo pecl upgrade inotify` says that there is

> Nothing to upgrade

So how can I obtain this extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the last stable version of Inotify (2020-12-18) can be installed without any problems :D
I just installed it with success the version 3.0.0!
https://pecl.php.net/package/inotify

Answer (score 1):

I got it work by compiling it from source. You can download the latest version [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/inotify) (should be `>=2.0.0` I belive).

Unzip the downloaded `.tgz`, go into the unzipped folder and then proceed to execute the following commands:

```
phpize7.4  # this is the important command
./configure
make clean
make
make install
```

That will compile the library with `20190902` and install it in `/usr/lib/php/20190902`:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/php/20190902/ | grep inotify
inotify.so
```

I trust you know how to enable the extension then; but in case you don't, first you'll need to create a file in `/etc/php/7.4/mods-available` named `inotify.ini` with the following contents: `extension=inotify.so` in order to reference the mod. So it'd look like this:

```
$ cat /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/inotify.ini 
extension=inotify.so
```

Then you can just enable the mod for every SAPI in version 7.4: `phpenmod -v 7.4 -s ALL inotify`. Probably then reset `php7.4-fpm`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll give it a try if.... is it easily uninstallable or do I have to memorize where I have copied that library ? Because I guess I cannot remove that via `apt` or `apt-get` ...

Comment: With a bit of luck they added a `make uninstall` rule, though I don't think they're that generous. You can check what's going to be installed doing a dry run with `make -n install` that details step by step what it would do but doesn't execute anything. Probably for uninstalling though you can just remove the compiled lib from `/usr/lib/php/20190902/inotify.so`, that should be enough.